# How to check if a game is installed more than once, so that I can remove duplicates?

Tags: steam

I've moved quite a few hard drives from past PCs & laptops into my current PC. Is there anyway to check if I've installed say... Hades on one of my previous laptops? Even if it's also installed to my PC hard drive as well.

Basically, I would like to remove any duplicates to get back some drive space.

I already have added each Steam library location from each hard drive into Steam.

Comment: I feel it shouldn't be all that hard to just sift through your steam library folder on each of the drives and compare them.  I believe Steam will create a game folder for each game and typically give the folder the same name as the game (or something similar to it).  I would just open up a few File Explorer windows with each one being opened to a library folder for each drive and compare them.

Comment: Maybe that is the best solution. I clicked "Ready to Play" to see only what is installed. That cut down my library from the like... 300ish to 92. Not as overwhelming to go look around lol. I leave the question in case anyone comes up with something easier/more specific. I can't check right this second anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If confronted to this problem, I'd do this:

Take something that would map your hard drive like this https://windirstat.net/

Games should be big chunks so they will appear as big cubes.

And then its the long and boring job of listing what is on what harddrive, to then figure out what is duped.

This solution would get any game, even those not installed in steamapps. But the comment is right, you could just look into the steamapps folder and 95% of games should be a folder in there.

Comment: I was really hoping Steam had some built in functionality for this, guess not.

Comment: A similar (also freeware) alternative that I'm a fan of: https://www.mindgems.com/products/Folder-Size/Folder-Size.html

Comment: @dimwittedanimal my other solution would have been to just scrap everything and redownload. Quicker, but if you have bandwidth limits, its problematic. And depending on how big the download is, you will choke your network for a decent while.

Comment: @Fredy31 that's what I did. uninstalled everything

Comment: or space sniffer: http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of Stream being able to detect duplicates, but Steam's library folders do have a common structure. All games are installed under the \steamapps\common directory. You could check under that directory on each of your drives and see if you find the same game folder there as your primary library drive and just delete it.

If the potential duplicate in question was installed on the old hard drive outside of Steam, then you would have to do some searching in directories such as Program Files and delete it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the game folder name across your hard drives. If you are on Linux you could use a command like this:

> find / -type d -name "Game folder name"

On Windows you can search from the start menu or file explorer. On Mac use search in Finder.

After getting the results be careful with what you delete as a single game install could potentially use multiple folders. For example a Unity made game in my Steam library use folders both under .config/unity3d and under .steam in my home directory.

Using "Manage -> Browse local files" from Steam will show the currently used location for the main game files (under .steam in my case).